# Unable to install pip3 in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am trying to install pip3 in my anaconda environment. But I am getting following error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Here are the errors:

```
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libexpat1-dev amd64 2.2.0-2ubuntu0.1   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80] Ign:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libpython3.5-dev amd64 3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.2
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libpython3-dev amd64 3.5.3-1   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80] Ign:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 python3.5-dev amd64 3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.2
Err:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 python3-dev amd64 3.5.3-1   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 libexpat1-dev amd64 2.2.0-2ubuntu0.1   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 libpython3.5-dev amd64 3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.2   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 python3.5-dev amd64 3.5.3-1ubuntu0~17.04.2    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Refer to:[pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)